# Converting my user xxxxx account into a normal account

Tags: support, login, display-names

When I joined stack exchange on phone, in a haste, instead of signing up, I directly joined and got a user xxxxx account.

Now, I want to login on laptop but can't. 
How do I convert my userxxxx account to a normal account with display name and password that I can use anywhere.

Comment: Edit your profile and change the display name. Profit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your account is normal, this's the default username, userxxxxx. So, since your account isn't unregistered, it does have a password.

If you forgot your password, you can try to recover it. You can also change your display name using the device you are logged in to by going to https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/edit.